# Is it possible to pass a string from Java to JSP with Java Class?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, parameter-passing

I need to create a string (sql statement) which might be pass to 2 or more jsp files. Recommended method is "[by accessing the ServletContext attributes via Java scriptlet or the applicationScope via EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15280522/get-the-results-of-java-into-jsp)". But, is there a simple way to pass the string from java class to the jsp? Something like below?

**Java**

```
public class SharedSQL extends HttpServlet{

public String example() {

    String sqlstmt = "select ABC from ABC";

    return sqlstmt;
}

}
```

**JSP**

```
<%
     SharedSQL sqlStatement = new SharedSQL() ;
     String sqlstmt = sqlStatement.example();
     db4.query ( sqlstmt ) ;
%>
```

I am new to servlet/JSP 'things', need some hints and tips.

Comment: First thing's first. Go through our `jstl` and `jsp` wikis. Do not use scriptlets.

Comment: how stupid I am in the pass, I'm now started coding project with jstl in jsp. really appreciate...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Servlet do like below

```
public class SharedSQL extends HttpServlet{

    doGet(request ,response){
         request.setAttribute("sqlstmt", "select ABC from ABC");
    }
}
```

in jsp do like below

```
<%
     String sqlstmt = request.getAttribute("sqlstmt") 
     db4.query ( sqlstmt ) ;
%>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also set it in the session attribute by

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("string",value) //you can set string, object in the value
```

Then directly access the value by using EL expression in jsp

```
${string}
```